# Timeseries AVG aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to calculate avg state of devices, in time periods. Devices sending events irregularly, so it can be periods of time without events, in this case need to use latest event. In fact this is 1/0 time sequence.

I will describe several cases, for better task understanding:

```
Event 1 - time 6:00, state 0
Event 2 - time 9:00, state 1
Event 3 - time 15:00, state 0
```

In this sequence I need to know AVG state for requested time periods, as example:

```
AVG from 7:00 to 8:00 = 0
AVG from 8:00 to 10:00 = 0.5
AVG from 10:00 to 15:00 = 1

AVG from 8:00 to 12:00 = 0.75
```

I'm trying different approaches to do this, but still cannot calculate right values.

For now I came to solution to index periods in which state is same, and then request ranges to find included periods - but in this case AVG not considering about time length in period, so

```
AVG from 8:00 to 12:00 = 0.75
```

will be **0.5**.

May be such approach is wrong, and I need different document index, or may be I need to pipe aggregations?

Elasticsearch code for reproduce.

```
PUT state_events
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "device_id":{
        "type": "long"
      },
      "state":{
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "from":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_hour_minute"
      },
       "to":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_hour_minute"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST state_events/_doc
{
  "device_id": 1,
  "state": true,
  "from": "2019-07-29T04:00",
  "to": "2019-07-29T6:00"
}

POST state_events/_doc
{
  "device_id": 1,
  "state": false,
  "from": "2019-07-29T06:00",
  "to": "2019-07-29T9:00"
}

POST state_events/_doc
{
  "device_id": 1,
  "state": true,
  "from": "2019-07-29T09:00",
  "to": "2019-07-29T15:00"
}

# 08:00 - 12:00
GET state_events/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "cc1310_id": {
              "value": "1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "from": {
                    "lte": "2019-07-29T12:00",
                    "gte": "2019-07-29T08:00"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "to": {
                    "lte": "2019-07-29T12:00",
                    "gte": "2019-07-29T08:00"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "from": {
                          "lte": "2019-07-29T08:00"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "to": {
                          "gte": "2019-07-29T12:00"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "avg_state": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "state"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have right avg value that will consider time?